# Tcl file parser for PYTHON

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, tcl, pyparsing

I have a .tcl file.

Is there any parser available which directly extracts data from .tcl file ? I don't want to use REGEX for this task. Is pyparsing will work for this problem ?

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the data"? Are you wanting to get the values of glbal variables? Do you want to run the code?

Comment: sorry for confusion. I want to parse the texts from my .tcl file. so for example this link is to parse S-expression file. http://sexpdata.readthedocs.org/en/latest/                   so it there any similar way for .tcl file

Comment: Do you have a sample of the file that you want to parse? What we're trying to figure out is whether there some way to determine “this bit is interesting” when doing the parsing?

Answer (score 1):

.tcl files are not data files, they are programming scripts, written in the Tcl programming language.

The Tcl language is extremely flexible in form and style, which makes writing a general-purpose parser a substantial project, whether in pyparsing or any other package. I encourage people, when they are embarking on a new pyparsing project, to begin by roughing out the BNF for the language, to whatever level of detail they want.  [This page from the Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1643) implies that developing a BNF for Tcl is not at all straightforward, if even possible.

It is very unlikely that anyone will respond to your question with an answer containing your Tcl-parser-implemented-in-Python.  Perhaps there is a Tcl subset that you are particularly focused on - if you were to post some sample Tcl code and what you want to get from it, you are more likely to get helpful responses.

Comment: While doing the job _in general_ is hard, you could probably handle a normal sane Tcl script more easily. It's only cases where people are passing scripts around as arguments to user procedures that get really quite tricky to parse correctly…